# Gmail search where does not iclude - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail gem within my rails app: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

I am able to search for email with subjects containing the word "Urgent" `gmail.inbox.search(subject: "Urgent").each do |email|`

How do I search for emails that do not include the word "Urgent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the gmail search syntax with `gm` key

```
gmail.inbox.search(gm: "subject: -'Urgent'")
```

You can also find the list of syntax you can use with `gm` [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Comment: For more search options, check [Googles Advanced Search page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: I gave the link in the answer ;)